# Is there a function to convert HSL to color:int in actionscript?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, colors, rgb, hsl

I want to define color value by using HSL(Hue, Saturation, Lightness) not RGB.
Does actionscript have a function for that?

For example, I want to write code like the following:

```
var color:int = hsl(10, 90, 30);
sprite.graphics.lineStyle(2, color);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No built-in way, but there are many functions available online to do the conversion. For example these [two JavaScript functions](http://mjijackson.com/2008/02/rgb-to-hsl-and-rgb-to-hsv-color-model-conversion-algorithms-in-javascript) (they might need to be slightly refactored to compile with AS3 but it should just be minor changes):

```
/**
 * Converts an RGB color value to HSL. Conversion formula
 * adapted from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_color_space.
 * Assumes r, g, and b are contained in the set [0, 255] and
 * returns h, s, and l in the set [0, 1].
 *
 * @param   Number  r       The red color value
 * @param   Number  g       The green color value
 * @param   Number  b       The blue color value
 * @return  Array           The HSL representation
 */
function rgbToHsl(r, g, b){
    r /= 255, g /= 255, b /= 255;
    var max = Math.max(r, g, b), min = Math.min(r, g, b);
    var h, s, l = (max + min) / 2;

    if(max == min){
        h = s = 0; // achromatic
    }else{
        var d = max - min;
        s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min);
        switch(max){
            case r: h = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6 : 0); break;
            case g: h = (b - r) / d + 2; break;
            case b: h = (r - g) / d + 4; break;
        }
        h /= 6;
    }

    return [h, s, l];
}

/**
 * Converts an HSL color value to RGB. Conversion formula
 * adapted from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_color_space.
 * Assumes h, s, and l are contained in the set [0, 1] and
 * returns r, g, and b in the set [0, 255].
 *
 * @param   Number  h       The hue
 * @param   Number  s       The saturation
 * @param   Number  l       The lightness
 * @return  Array           The RGB representation
 */
function hslToRgb(h, s, l){
    var r, g, b;

    if(s == 0){
        r = g = b = l; // achromatic
    }else{
        function hue2rgb(p, q, t){
            if(t < 0) t += 1;
            if(t > 1) t -= 1;
            if(t < 1/6) return p + (q - p) * 6 * t;
            if(t < 1/2) return q;
            if(t < 2/3) return p + (q - p) * (2/3 - t) * 6;
            return p;
        }

        var q = l < 0.5 ? l * (1 + s) : l + s - l * s;
        var p = 2 * l - q;
        r = hue2rgb(p, q, h + 1/3);
        g = hue2rgb(p, q, h);
        b = hue2rgb(p, q, h - 1/3);
    }

    return [r * 255, g * 255, b * 255];
}
```

Then use `ColorTransform` to get the `uint` RGB value:

```
var c:Array = hslToRgb(10, 90, 30);
var t:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, c[0], c[1], c[2]);
var color:uint = t.color;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Flex4, you can use class [**HSBColor**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/HSBColor.html). It has two static methods: *convertHSBtoRGB* and convertRGBtoHSB.

Comment: Just beware that HSB != HSL.